# Implementing Google Site Search in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-search

I've installed Google Site Search module (gss) in Drupal 7. I've bought the site search from google custom engine and inserted the search engine ID in the search settings under Google Site search and made it the default search module.

However i'm yet to see any results.

What might I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Modify submission handler for search_block()

```
$search = trim(filter_xss($form_state['values']['search']));
drupal_goto('search/gss/' . $search);
```